# Subtract from dict (python) until value is reached

Tags: python

I am new to using dict, and would like to subtract from the dict until I have reached a set value. The code for subtraction of a single value from a dict is this:

```
for k in dict_:
dict_[k] -= 1
```

Would it be possible to make this code only subtract data from a value in a dict if it is greater than a value that I set (for example 0)?

Comment: Did you try using `if`?

Comment: Please add your existing code/approach

Comment: Your requirement is translated very directly to code: `if dict_[k] > threshold: ...`

Comment: If you found any of the answers helpful,  consider accepting / upvoting. It'll help you as well as the answerer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this

```py
threshold_val = 5 # say

for key, val in my_dict.items():
    if val > threshold_val:
        my_dict[key] = val - 1 # say we want to decrement by one
```

Answer (score 0):

That should be pretty easy:

```
def foo(stop_val, subtraction_limit):
    for k in dict_:
        if k == stop_val:
            break # exit loop    
        if dict_[k] > subtraction_limit:
            dict_[k] -= 1
```

You should note that you have **no control** of the order in which the dictionary's keys are being iterated over. It might be different that the order in which you initiated the dictionary.
That means that iteration could stop at any point, and leave some values un-subtracted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
#example set value
set_value = 7
for k in d:
    if (d[k] > set_value):
        d[k] -= 1
```